# Trying to understand complex function

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, artificial-intelligence

I am doing this AI project in which I need to create an array of any 5 consecutive numbers. For example [[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]]. Luckily, I am following a tutorial and got this line to do it: `Data = [[[i+j] for i in range(5)] for j in range(100)]`. I want to know what this means. I have strong knowledge of Python but have never used this type of notation.

Comment: The search term you are looking for is `list comprehensions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
Data = [[[i+j] for i in range(5)] for j in range(100)]
```

Can be cut down to two pieces:

```
[[i+j] for i in range(5)]
```

and

```
[[[i+j] for i in range(5)] for j in range(100)]
```

Both of them contain a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python). Let's evaluate the first one.

```
[[i+j] for i in range(5)]
```

This is similar to:

```
elements = []
for i in range(5):
    elements.append([i + j])
```

Which produces:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

The outer loop performs this task a hundred times, but increases the inner loop start value by 1 on each run.  So we generate 100 lists, containing a list of 5 elements, each containing a list of 1 element.